# Text Change in a textbox

Tags: javascript, html, text, textbox

I have a text box that the contents change on page reload, but what I was wondering is how to make it change after a specified amount of time. Is this possible without flash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy and paste this code in to a html file and check it out, should be easy enough for you to edit to fit your own needs. Enjoy :o)

```
<html>
        <head>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            //Change these messages to what ever you would like to display in the textbox
            //You can add or remove any as you see necessary
            var messages = new Array(
                "Hello",
                "there",
                "my",
                "name",
                "is",
                "Chief17!"
            );
            var i = 0;
            function changeText()
            {
                document.getElementById("tb").value = messages[i];
                if(i < messages.length -1)
                {
                    i++;
                }
                else
                {
                    i = 0;
                }
            }
            </script>
        </head>
        <!--Change the 1000 to how long you want to wait in between message changes (1000 is 1 second)-->
        <body onLoad="setInterval('changeText()',1000)">
            <input type="text" id="tb" />
        </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

`setInterval('changeTextFunction()',1000);` *Second param, 1 sec = 1000.*

Answer (score 1):

For changing the text in a textbox you can

```
 txtFld = document.getElementById("yourTextBox");
 txtFld.value = "New value";
```

To set a timer, like a countdown timer, you could use a variation of something like this:

```
<script> 
 <!-- 
      // 
  var milisec=0 
  var seconds=30 
  document.counter.d2.value='30' 

  function display(){ 
  if (milisec<=0){ 
      milisec=9 
      seconds-=1 
  } 
  if (seconds<=-1){ 
      milisec=0 
      seconds+=1 
  } 
  else 
      milisec-=1 
  document.counter.d2.value=seconds+"."+milisec 
  setTimeout("display()",100) 
} 
display() 
--> 
</script>
```